# Remove all surrounding margins in a pdf

Tags: pdf, automation, margins

I use a tablet to read several pdfs. Because of additional margins , the actual text on each page gets rather small. I would like to remove all whitespace before any actual content. This can mean that I will have unequal page sizes, which I am fine with.

Most tools allow you to crop based on a rectangle. I want something that can go page wise and remove white spaces around content as needed (thus, if there is just a little bit of content at the centre, it will be much bigger.

Is there any tool like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pdfcrop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pdfcrop.1.html) should be able to do what you want. According to the man page:

> **pdfcrop**  is  a  utility to calculate and remove empty margins from each
>          page in the input PDF file.  The resulting  output  file  occupies  the
>          minimal  paper  size  needed for the contents and is therefore suitable
>          for inclusion as a graphic

Comment: I found this solution minutes before you posted.